# How to add "quickly" mesh to an armature?

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature

I know i can simply create one vertex, extrude vertices from there, add a "skin modifier" and then click on "create armature" and so i have a very quick armature + mesh setup - which i really appreciate.

Is there a "similar" trick to add mesh to an existing armature?

Comment: with a script you can create a skeleton mesh from the bones fairly quickly. Then mark the roots of the limbs as roots for the skin modifier and you have a stick figure.

Comment: There is the *Object: Skinify Rig* addon. It comes with Blender and can create a mesh from selected bones: https://youtu.be/v4K8I0gSIuQ